# What is the correct folder structure and naming convention for pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

Why does pytest not collect my test?

My folder structure:

```
src
|-- examplemodule.py
tests
|-- test_examplemodule.py
```

Content of `test_examplemodule.py`:

```
from unittest import TestCase

class TestExamplemodule(TestCase):
    def run_mock_example(self):
        # do stuff
```

Running `python3 -m pytest tests` gives me `collected 0 tests`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function name should start or end with `test_` or `_test` respectively. So in your case `test_run_mock_example()`